# Migrating data from one table of one database to other table of other database

Tags: migration

I am trying to migrate data from  table A of database DB1 to table B of database DB2 using java and Oracle.

I am using java 1.8 and my source database has Oracle 11g and destination database has Oracle 12c.

I made structure (scema, tables )of destination database in source database. And migrating as by making use of  *insert into dest select * from source* query in java . but as the number of records in source table in millions so it's  consuming time.. and later on this migrated data i want to export into my actual destination so that too will going to take time.

As per my little knowledge.. i think I can't use prepared statement with 2 connection. Because my table consists of 400 to 500 columns , so binding that many columns with prepared statement is not a good idea. Also my structure of source and destination tables are different.  I made the field mapping in properties file where I mapped the old field to new field for insert into select * from tbl query. Like my source table has column as col0001 and the corresponding column in destination is ref_no. So this too will not allow me to use prepared statement. But by making use of statement in java i can migrate data in single dB only.

I tried with dblink also. But for clob datatype i am not able to migrate data.

Kindly provide the solution if anyone did something like this previously.

Answer (score 0):

For a one-off copy, you can do a direct mode insert:

```
insert /*+ APPEND */ into local_table select * from table@database_link;
```

Here are some other related [links](https://www.google.ca/search?q=export%20table%20from%20one%20oracle%20database%20to%20another).

Comment: It gives error as cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables